# Trying to have a clicked-on button display it's value attribute

Tags: javascript

Here's my code

```
for(var i = 0; i<tabs.length; i++)
        {
                alert(tabs[i].getAttribute('value'));
                tabs[i].onclick = function() {
                        alert("clicked");
                        alert(tab[i].getAttribute('value'));
                };
        }
```

This is all in the window.onload function.  The first alert works, i.e. the value of each input element is alerted when the page loads.  Then, when I click one of the buttons, "clicked" is alerted, but not the value attribute.

Say I have three tabs with the values "home", "about", and "contact".  Is there a way to have access to (in this case, simply alert) the value (or any other) attribute when they're clicked without manually writing each onclick method?

Thanks

Comment: You try with this.getAttribute('value') instead of tab[i].getAttribute('value')?

Comment: @GonzaloBahamondez that did the trick.  So in an onclick function, 'this' is the element that was clicked?

Comment: This represent the element in the callback function, read about function scopes.

Comment: @user3391564: `this` refers to the element the handler was bound to. Read http://www.quirksmode.org/js/introevents.html to learn all there is to know about event handling.

Answer (score 2):

Did You try with:

```
this.getAttribute('value')
```

instead of

```
tab[i].getAttribute('value')?
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you meant

```
tabs[i].getAttribute('value')
```

instead of

```
tab[i].getAttribute('value')
```

---

Either ways, The problem here is that the value of **i** is long changed before the click events are fired.

The simplest solution is to wrap the code with `(function (i) {` & `})(i);`

This works as a new copy of **i** is created & passed to the click event.

Here is a [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/99NYV/1/) with your code. And this [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/99NYV/) after the changes.

Updated code:

```
for (var i = 0; i < tabs.length; i++) {
        alert(tabs[i].getAttribute('value'));
        (function (i) {
            tabs[i].onclick = function () {
                alert("clicked");
                alert(tabs[i].getAttribute('value'));
            }
        })(i);
    }
```